# Raspberry Pi always boots into terminal after changes in autostart

Tags: boot, lxterminal

Recently I changed the LXDE autostart setup to automatically open the terminal after booting. I used the following two lines of code:

```
nano ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

and

```
@lxterminal
```

This worked, but now the Raspberry Pi always boots into this terminal and I can't get out of this. 
I'm a beginner, so please take it easy on me. 
Very thankful for any sort of help

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with: "*I can't get out of this*"? Just type `exit` on the command line and the terminal should close.

Comment: Thank's for the quick anwser, but unfortunately it's not that simple.
If I exit the terminal, I only get a black screen. I think I somehow deactivated the graphical GUI by changing the rc.local for the autostart, but this is really out of my league. I also reversed everything I've done, but it made no difference.

Comment: @Raspberryfan Do you do something with rc.local? What do you do? And do you start the terminal with `~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`? Please edit your question and complete it with this important information. Please take note that using `/etc/rc.local` has limitations due to [Compatibility with SysV](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities/). We have seen many problems here on this site using it. Following the recommendation of the developers from **systemd** you should avoid using it.

Answer (score 0):

One easier way is to set Rpi to boot into terminal mode (multi-user.target) by 'sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target', and reboot.
Once it reboots, you can remove the autostart, and revert to graphical environment by doing 'sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target' and rebooting.